# Replace parent directory name with one of my choice

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to replace the parent folder of a path with a name of my choice.

```
exports.uploadDirectory = async function(dir, customer) {
var fullPathArray = [];
var params = [];
// Read all folders, subfolder and files and add them to an array
fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(file => {
 let fullPath = path.join(dir, file);
 if (fs.lstatSync(fullPath).isDirectory()) {
    exports.uploadDirectory(fullPath);
  } else {
            fullPathArray.push(fullPath);
  }  
 });
      // Loop through each file found and add it to the object params array
      fullPathArray.forEach(function(value){
      let init_value = value.split(/\/(.+)/)[1]; // Removing old parent folder
      console.log(customer + '/' + init_value); // Thought this may work but returns the below
      params.push({ Bucket: config.S3.bucket, Key: init_value, Body: fs.createReadStream(value) });
 });

// More Stuff here
};
```

**Console Log prints**

```
undefined/New Folder 2/test22.js
myCustomer/index.html
myCustomer/test.js
```

As you can see the first item which has a sub directory returns undefined. But the files in the parent directory work fine.

**Expected**

```
myCustomer/New Folder 2/test22.js
myCustomer/index.html
myCustomer/test.js
```

**EDIT**

value is;

```
New Folder/New Folder 2/test22.js
New Folder/index.html
New Folder/test.js
```

init_value is;

```
  New Folder 2/test22.js
  index.html
  test.js
```

Call

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
await content.uploadDirectory("./New Folder", "myCustomer");
};
```

Comment: could you add the detail of `value` by console.log it above `let init_value`?

Comment: @hgb123 Just added above now.

Comment: I reproduced in my local and see nothing wrong https://imgur.com/a/NFh0EPB

Comment: Huh.  That def. helps! I have an idea what may be wrong. I am using AWS Lambda to do this and the way/where I invoke the function may be causing this. I'll try something and send out an update.

Comment: When I declare and assign a local variable 'customer' as you have, it works fine.  But when I pass it as an argument in the function, it does not.  Weird.

Comment: hmm how did you call `uploadDirectory `, and did you use `customer` anywhere else in *More stuff here*?

Comment: I added the call above.  And no, more stuff is just the upload to S3.  Its 4 lines of code that just does the upload. I removed that upload and same thing occurs.

Comment: seem the problem is here `exports.uploadDirectory(fullPath)`, you forgot to call it with `customer`, it should be `exports.uploadDirectory(fullPath, customer)`, please have a try and let me know

Comment: *Slaps face. 100% right - works now! It's been a long morning..I really appreciate that! Thank you very much.  You can add an answer below and I'll mark it as correct

Comment: My pleasure ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem lies in here

```
exports.uploadDirectory(fullPath)
```

You forgot to call it with customer, it should be

```
exports.uploadDirectory(fullPath, customer)
```